# Remove everything before certain character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How do I remove everything before the 6th colon in this text for example:

```
123:::12423:122343:123:1234:example
1212d3:::123:123453:12333:12345:example
12dd3:::12663:1223423:123:123456:example
123:::123:123:123:1234567:example
124tsd3:::121233:123:123:12346578:example
125sdf3:::123:1254353:123:123456789:example
```

So then I would be left with:

```
1234:example
12345:example
123456:example
1234567:example
12346578:example
123456789:example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex: `.*?(\d+:example)` and replace it with `$1`.

For an explanation of this regular expression, see https://regex101.com/r/YN1uIc/3

[image: Screenshot of notepad++ replace window]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with other strings than digit and the word example:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+:(?=[^:]+:[^:]+$)`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
.+          : 1 or more any character
:           : literally :
(?=         : start lookahead, make sure we have the following after
  [^:]+     : 1 or more any character but :
  :         : literally :
  [^:]+     : 1 or more any character but :
  $         : end of line
)           : end lookahead
```

*DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Result for given example:**

```
1234:example
12345:example
123456:example
1234567:example
12346578:example
123456789:example
```

Comment: Up voted!, love the line-by-line explanation for the regex.

Comment: @PaulT. : Thanks